# Codeigniter 4 get configuration array by passing a dbgroup

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Many websites including official site state about connecting database connections on a `dbgroup`, however I hardly found a website that talks about getting only an array of configuration.

This idea is that we can make several data adapter objects like `OAuth\Pdo` without an unused real database connection to get the config.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from looking at the system class `CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig`.

The files in `app/Config` including `app/Config/Database.php` are instances of `BaseConfig`, which means we can get the public properties of  `Database` config by:

```
$database = new \Config\Database();
```

Getting configuration array by passing a dbgroup will then remain in three steps:

Duplicate a database connection in `.env` and update the values:

```
database.newdbgroup.hostname = localhost
database.newdbgroup.database = newdbgroup
database.newdbgroup.username = newdbgroup-username
database.newdbgroup.password = newdbgroup-password
database.newdbgroup.DBDriver = MySQLi
database.newdbgroup.DBPrefix =
```

Duplicate a database connection in `app/Config/Database.php`. We should not update the values this time:

```
public $newdbgroup = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

Check the expected outcome:

```
$database = new \Config\Database();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($database->newdbgroup);
echo '</pre>';

exit();
```

Which outputs:

```
array(17) {
  ["DSN"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hostname"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["username"]=>
  string(19) "newdbgroup-username"
  ["password"]=>
  string(19) "newdbgroup-password"
  ["database"]=>
  string(10) "newdbgroup"
  ["DBDriver"]=>
  string(6) "MySQLi"
  ["DBPrefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pConnect"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["DBDebug"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["charset"]=>
  string(4) "utf8"
  ["DBCollat"]=>
  string(15) "utf8_general_ci"
  ["swapPre"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["encrypt"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["compress"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["strictOn"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["failover"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["port"]=>
  int(3306)
}
```